# Format Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the Below format.

```
time_range:6 [▼
  "limit_by" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Day",
    1 => "Date"
  ]
  "day" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "mon",
    1 => ""
  ]
  "date" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "",
    1 => "2015-03-14"
  ]
  "from_time" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "07:00:00",
    1 => "10:30:00"
  ]
  "to_time" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "20:00:00",
    1 => "16:30:00"
  ]
  "max_covers_limit" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5",
    1 => "3"
  ]
]
```

How can I format the above array in PHP so that I can display a table which looks similar to the below format:

## Limit By | Day or Date | From Time  | To Time  | Max Limit

### Day      |     Mon            |  07:00:00  | 20:00:00 |     5

### Date     |    2015-03-14      |  10:30:00  | 16:30:00 |     3

Please provide me a way.
This is what I Tried:

```
foreach($time_range as $time_range)
{
$block_time_range['limit_by'] = $time_range['limit_by'];
$block_time_range['day'] = $time_range['day'];
$block_time_range['date'] = $time_range['date'];
$block_time_range['from_time'] = $time_range['from_time'];
$block_time_range['to_time'] = $time_range['to_time'];
$block_time_range['max_covers'] = $time_range['max_covers'];
}
```

Comment: You can use PHP foreach to loop over a PHP array and echo HTML along with the array element values. Try that and post the code you've tried and the output here if you have any problems.

Comment: I tried to loop through the array but the thing is that I need to transform the array so that the Html is formatted correctly

Comment: Show in your question the code you tried and the output you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the following code.

```
<?php

$keys = array_keys($time_range);

// count the number of rows based on the first column
$rows = count($time_range[key($time_range)]);

echo '<table><thead><tr>';

// show header
foreach($keys as $key) {
  echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

// for every row
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i) {
  echo '<tr>';
  // for every column
  foreach($time_range as $column) {
    echo '<td>'.$column[$i].'</td>';
  }

  echo '</tr>';  
}

echo '</tbody></table>';

?>
```